# What is the thread gauge on gas tank straps 81 chevy

Tags: chevrolet

Does anybody know what bolt size I need for those gas tank straps on an 81ish chevy c30?  I lost one of the bolts and the other bolt is kind of a pain to take off an on again.

Comment: What is the head size of the one which remains? If it's a 9/16" head, it's more than likely a 3/8"-16 thread. You'd just have to ensure the bolt is long enough. If you can give me the head size, I can figure out what the thread is for you.

Comment: sorry my bad, its a knut that goes on the end of one these things  https://www.1aauto.com/fuel-tank-with-strap-set/i/1afrk00014?f=445498&y=1981&utm_campaign=gb_csv_br&utm_content=FRK&gclid=Cj0KCQjw7YblBRDFARIsAKkK-dK_Va2_gdHb4FIuS68o57htvYLLdNz91My_82gBhMIrm6teyOihbdkaAkTbEALw_wcB

Comment: Still, what is the head size of the nut (or opposing bolt)?

Comment: It is a 5/8 head

Comment: It is most likely a 7/16"-14 thread. Most nuts/bolts of this type are coarse threaded. I'm surprised, though ... usually these are captured nuts, to make installation easier. You sure something isn't rusted through?

Comment: There are also about three metal braces with a bunch of other bolts.  they're in pretty bad shape.  I think the two straps hold it tight.

Comment: Some good ie in focus images with a ruler for scale would help.

Comment: I have seen 5/8 head nuts for a 3/8 stud before.

Comment: I found a pair of 7/16"-14 nuts.  We'll see if it fits probably today or tomorrow.   That should make the truck start right??  jk...we have a lot more to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annnnd the winner is 3/8-16. Thanks for playing folks.